# handle not possible to fast-forward aborting without using rebase

Tags: git

when I pull code from branch `develop` into `dev/jiangxiaoqiang`, shows error message:

```
not possible to fast-forward aborting
```

then I using `rebase` to merge the code into current branch, it generate a new commit with the same commit message but different SHA code. when I am using command to check the log history:

```
git log --all --grep='Window'
```

shows git log message like this:

```
commit 41db897c1e1b5aab3a9fc55904b5d192831b81f2
Author: xi.chen <xi.chen@example.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 26 17:14:19 2022 +0800

    feat: add Window、Session

commit d8f7e8e92778ed7944074eaade8b5aaa89a19905
Author: xi.chen <xi.chen@example.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 26 17:14:19 2022 +0800

    feat: add Window、Session
```

why did this happen? how to avoid this problem?

Comment: A ff is not possible when the branches have diverged (there are revisions in two different directions from the last common commit, for simplicity).... in that case, you _can't_ force a ff. You need to rebase or merge in order to get the revisions from both branches joined together (and I haven't touched in the topic that the upstream branch should not be rebased). How can you make sure you will always be able to ff? By keeping a branch fixed while you work on another (not the best thing to try to achieve in a multi-developer project).

Comment: By the way..... that looks like you are using `--ff-only` when pulling.

Comment: @eftshift0: in the very latest versions of Git, you have to pick a pull action (merge, fast-forward, or rebase) and the OP probably picked `ff` (fast forward only, usually the right choice).

Comment: Why is it a problem? `git log --all` shows history of all branches. You likely have a different branch pointing to your commit before it got rebased.